# [turtlemimic.launch] is neither a launch file in package [test_launch] nor is [test_launch] a launch file name?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done as the tutorials of ROS in the part of 'UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch'
but the still gets the error '[turtlemimic.launch] is neither a launch file in package [test_launch] nor is [test_launch] a launch file name'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86526/%5Bturtlemimic.launch%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5Btest_launch%5D-nor-is-%5Btest_launch%5D-a-launch-file-name?/) by [YUBO.ZUZU](https://answers.ros.org/users/7346/yubo.zuzu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should "overlay your workspace on top of your environment", so
cd catkin_ws
source devel/setup.bash

then launch your file!

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bahaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/10376/bahaa/) on 2014-01-01**:
i did this but sill have the same problem

**Comment by [candidcypher](https://answers.ros.org/users/20435/candidcypher/) on 2015-09-14**:
Worked perfectly. However I do have a follow up question: When you initialize a catkin workspace, shouldn't that already be taken care of?

**Comment by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) on 2015-09-14**:
You can add the path of your catkin_ws in ~/.bashrc .
***sudo gedit ~/.bashrc***
add the path of your catkin workspace in bashrc
***YourPath/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash***
and then run in terminal "**source ~/.bashrc**"
And then you never get this error.

**Comment by [Praveen Nellihela](https://answers.ros.org/users/74256/praveen-nellihela/) on 2021-05-21**:
I had the same issue and I have already sourced the setup.bash. It turned out to be a spelling error in the command. I have typed beginner_tutorial"" instead of beginner_tutorial"s". If you get the same issue even after sourcing the setup.bash, double check the command to see if the spelling and names are correct. This might help.